# Writing event in excel relating to scrollColumn

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I want to write an open event which shift the excel window to a particular column when ever I open the excel. 
I am able to scroll the window with the help of module and button, the code used by me is:

```
Sheet9.Activate
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = temp
```

Here temp is a variable whose value changes.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

When you Open the Workbook, it triggers the `Workbook_Open` event.  Alternatively, when you Activate a Worksheet, it triggers the `Worksheet_Activate` event.

To scroll the screen to show a specific Cell on the Worksheet, you can use the `Range.Show` Method.  For example, to show Cell F10 on the ActiveSheet, you can use either of the following lines:

```
ActiveSheetRange("F10").Show
ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 6).Show
```

If you want to scroll to a Column without changing the Row, you will need to use `Window.ScrollRow` to work out which cells are on screen, like so:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveWindow.ScrollRow, 6).Show 'Scroll to the 6th column, Column F
```